# How to use logical operators in preg_replace() & preg_match in php

Tags: php

How to use "&&" and "||" in php functions like preg_replace & preg_match.

Comment: You should learn regular expressions.

Comment: You'll need to explain what you're trying to accomplish with this

Comment: Please provide an example of the code for which your question applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `|` as *or* in a regular expression.

```
^(abc|cde)\d$
```